# Regex to stop matching when either of two words show up

Tags: regex, string-matching

I want to stop capturing when either of two words show up, "directory" or "tag".

Text case 1:

```
"...input job: dentist directory job: hygenist </tag>"
```

Text case 2:

```
"...input job: dentist</tag>"
```

The **dentist** is what I want to capture. So basically I want the regex to start matching after "input job: " and stop matching when either `</tag>` OR `directory` occurs in the string. This is because `</tag>` or `directory` will always show up after **dentist**.

I've tried many different things. The closest I've come is this (which begins matching and doesn't reach an end case):

```
(?<=input job: )(\D*)(?= directory| <\/tag>)
```

Text case 1 is satisfied if I just use one of the end cases:

```
(?<=input job: )(\D*)(?= directory)
```

And Text case 2 is satisfied if I just use the other end case:

```
(?<=input job: )(\D*)(?= <\/tag>)
```

However, I want to cover both cases. I assumed putting the or conditional ("|") would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: This is not a code or regex writing service where you post your requirements and someone churns out something to match them What attempts have you made to solve this yourself? Please [edit] to include the most recent effort you've made and explain how it's not working as you'd expect. While you're doing so, add a tag to indicate what regex engine you're using, as there are major feature and syntax differences between them.

Comment: @KenWhite Apologies for not showing my attempts, I was trying to keep the post as clear as possible.

Comment: @gp_sflover I agree, I need to be more active in the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, my problem was that I wasn't using a lazy quantifier `*?` (match as few characters as possible). I was using a greedy quantifier `*` (match as many characters as possible). So everything I tried wasn't performing as expected. The following works perfectly:

```
(?<=input job:)(\D*?)(?=directory|<\/tag>)
```

it will grab everything after `input job:` and stop when it reaches either `directory` or `</tag>`